# How to visualize data of 300 files together based on every row and column in the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have 300 files (one file is equal to one hour) every file has different column names (`WRES_LD`, `RRES_LD`, `VRES_LD` and more) and all these 300 files contain same column name. Now, `WRES_LD`, `RRES_LD`, `VRES_LD` has total 1100 rows and out of those only 132 values has the data.

Now, I have to visualize the data for 300  (files) hours on the y-axis and for the x-axis for `LD=1` then `WRES_LD_RRES_LD`, `VRES_LD` for all the columns should have first row value plt on y-axis. similarly for `LD=2`.

I have combined all the 300 files column wise. So, I am thinking for making different data frames and then plot these values.

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,  delimiter=',' )
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
frame.to_csv('converted_Dataset/FinalRes/FinalwithouVres12.csv',index=False)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('converted_Dataset/FinalRes/FinalwithouVres12.csv')
x=df['WRES_LD'].iloc[1:57]
y=df['RRES_LD'].iloc[1:57]
z=df['VRES_LD'].iloc[1:57]
df = pd.DataFrame(x,y,z)
df
##df2 = pd.DataFrame(y,index=range(1,30,1),color'green')
#lines = df.plot.line()
#df.plot(kind='line',x=x,y=y,ax=ax)
#df.plot(kind='line',x=x,y=y, color='red', ax=ax)
#plt.show()
#lines
```

What's the best approach to solve this problem ?